# Migrating application into Tomcat7

Tags: java, apache, servlets, tomcat7, weblogic-10.x

I am migrating Weblogic 10 Application into Tomcat7.  Here are the steps that I have done so far.

I have taken each Weblogic instances code and placed into the ROOT directory of Tomcat, and then trying to access the URL but its not working. It is giving me the error (catalina.out log) as follows:

```
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] so no cleanup was performed for that container 
INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/j2ee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Am I following the right approach?

Comment: In my local tomcat server web applications are deployed to `wtpwebapps` folder. Or try to put it into `webapps` folder

Comment: i am trying to put into webapps folder itself. Still getting the same error